# Snowflake procedure JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' in ERR_LOGGING at

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need help on a small Snowflake stored procedure written in JavaScript, i am getting the following error,
JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' in ERR_LOGGING at ' , binds: [v_err_seq,APP_NAME,ERR_MSG, MISC_STR,v_time_st])"' position 10

The code is as follows,

```
    create or replace sequence SEQ_ERR;
create or replace table ERROR_LOG(ERR_SEQ NUMBER, APP_NAME VARCHAR(250), ERR_MSG VARCHAR(2500), MISC_STRING VARCHAR(2500), err_date timestamp);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ERR_LOGGING(app_name varchar, err_msg varchar, misc_str varchar )
returns string not null
language javascript
strict volatile
execute as caller
as
$$
try {
    var v_time_st = getScalar("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
    var v_err_seq = getScalar("SELECT SEQ_ERR.nextval");    
    error_msg = 'THis is in the line before the execute';
    var sqlCmd = `insert into ERROR_LOG (ERR_SEQ , APP_NAME, ERR_MSG , MISC_STRING, ERR_DATE) VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)`;
    stmt = snowflake.execute({ sqlText: sqlCmd, binds: [v_err_seq, APP_NAME, ERR_MSG, sqlCmd,v_time_st]});
    }
catch (err)  {
    result= " "
    result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
    result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
    result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;
    }  
function getScalar(queryString) {
    var out;
    cmd1 = {sqlText: queryString};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue(1);
    return out;
}

    
return result;
$$;

call ERR_LOGGING('TEST_APP', 'THis is an error messge', 'ON line 1');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems start on these lines:

```
var v_time_st = snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;"} );
var v_err_seq = snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "SELECT SEQ_ERR.nextval;"} );
```

When you run a SQL statement through the stored procedures API, it returns a table in the form of an object called a ResultSet. You're returning a ResultSet to these variables, not the values you want. In order to get the values, you need to use the `.next()` method of the ResultSet and then the `.getColumnValue()` method.

The problem then continues to the next line doing the insert. It's expecting scalar values for the binds but is sent variables containing ResultSets objects with all their attendant complexity.

It's a common practice to need to get single scalar values from a SQL statement. If you know for 100% certain that your query will return exactly one row and one column, you can use a helper function like this one called `getScalar`. Here's an example:

```
create or replace procedure FOO()
returns timestamp
language javascript
strict volatile
execute as caller
as
$$

var v_time_st = getScalar("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");

return v_time_st;

// Main function above, helper functions below.

function getScalar(queryString) {
    var out;
    cmd1 = {sqlText: queryString};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue(1);
    return out;
}

$$;

call foo();
```

You can keep that helper function below your main function and out of the way. From there you can do this to get your variables assigned how you need them:

```
var v_time_st = getScalar("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
var v_err_seq = getScalar("SELECT SEQ_ERR.nextval");
```

Based on your update, here's refactored code that should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ERR_LOGGING(app_name varchar, err_msg varchar, misc_str varchar )
returns string not null
language javascript
strict volatile
execute as caller
as
$$
try {
    var v_time_st = getScalar("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
    var v_err_seq = getScalar("SELECT SEQ_ERR.nextval");    
    var sqlCmd = `insert into ERROR_LOG (ERR_SEQ NUMBER, APP_NAME, ERR_MSG , MISC_STRING, ERR_DATE) VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)`;
    stmt = snowflake.execute({ sqlText: sqlCmd, binds: [P_BATCH_ID, JOB_NAME, error_msg1, sql_command]});
    }
catch (err)  {
    result= " "
    result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
    result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
    result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;
    }  
function getScalar(queryString) {
    var out;
    cmd1 = {sqlText: queryString};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue(1);
    return out;
}

    
return result;
$$;

call ERR_LOGGING('TEST_APP', 'THis is an error messge', 'ON line 1');
```

Comment: Thanks Greg for the explanation, i did what you said but getting an error as follows "JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' in ERR_LOGGING at ' , binds: [v_err_seq,APP_NAME,ERR_MSG, MISC_STR,v_time_st])"' position 10". The updated code is in the original question.

Comment: I updated my answer with the syntax error corrected. Scroll to the bottom for the revised code. Try now. I didn't create the table and sequence, but the syntax error is gone and the SQL tried to run. If it doesn't work, send the DDL for the table and sequence and I'll run with the SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the Help, I did some correction on the code and the updated code with the DDL is attached. Getting this error. "Failed: Code: 100183
  State: P0000
  Message: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 31 unexpected 'NUMBER'.
Stack Trace:
At Snowflake.execute, line 7 position 21"

Comment: When you get a SQL compilation error, the easiest way to see what the procedure tried to run is to look in the Query History tab.

Comment: Thanks for the help Greg, it worked